# The best way of caching data in a ClickOnce/WCF application?

Tags: c#, wcf, clickonce

I've got a SaaS application which is being deployed to clients as a ClickOnce app, where the client connects to my cloud server via a WCF NetTcp connection.  The data is all stored on the server, but the client needs to be able to see his data.

It's all working, but I'm having a bit of trouble when there's a lot of data to transfer, e.g. in one table a client might have about 3,000 records, and that takes an awful long time to come through the WCF connection.  So that's problem 1: how to pull the necessary data from the server.  Right now, trying to do it synchronously, it's simply timing out.  I could up the timeout limits, but that feels a bit too much like brute force.  Would you recommend some kind of asynchronous solution - and if so, how would you do that through WCF?

Problem 2: having got all this data down once, it would make sense to cache it and do some kind of background synchronization to make sure it stays fresh.  But how to cache it?  Should I ship a SQL Express DB with the ClickOnce app?  Or is there a simpler way?  And where can you save the cache data, bearing in mind the sandbox restrictions of a ClickOnce app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1, you can [invoke the operation that takes a long time asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx). Also consider not retrieving all 3000 records at once. If your use case allows, you could page the data.

For problem 2, yes you could cache it. You could do something as simple as an in-memory thread safe dictionary, or a thread safe singleton instance of the data if that makes sense. If you need to persist to disk, I would opt for a file based database [like SQL CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) or [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) so that there is no client installation required.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data and how much of it is allowed to be cached or synchronised you could look at the replication features in SQL Compact 3.5 (not 4.0) as this supports partial synchronisation with SQL server.

Failing that you could store the data in your own database locally (for this I'd recommend SQL Compact 4.0 rather than SQL Express) and then you'd have to have your own updating logic.

Alternatively if you don't need to cache the data for long you could use the Enterprise Library caching blocks and store the data in Application Storage. This method would be best suited if you wanted to cache queries and results rather than individual records.